# is this definition of the exterior/wedge product correct?

Tags: differential-geometry

let $E$ be a n-dimensional vector space.

the exterior product of a $k-$form $\alpha$ with a $l-$form $\beta$ is the $(k+l)-$ form given by the formula :

$$\frac{1}{k ! l!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} \text{sign}(\sigma)\alpha(x_{\sigma(1),\cdots,x_ \sigma(k)})\beta(x_{\sigma(k+1),\cdots,x_ \sigma(k+l)})$$

where $S_{k+l}$ denotes the permutation group of $\{1,\cdots,k+l\}$

this is a definition the teacher gave to the class of last year, this year he totally omitted totally the $\frac{1}{k! l!}$ and after some googling I've defintions with in addition to the $\frac{1}{k! l!}$ there's a ($k+l) !$
 on top.

my question is : which defintion is correct or which definition is most used ?

thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no a standard definition and the factors $k!,l!$ and $(k+l)!$ are always ''dancing''. It depends on the reference you work with. My first approach to exterior calculus was trough Szekeres' book, and use the first definition. Later, a teacher suggested me to change and add the other factors to the definition. It depended. The factors simplyfy some expressions and ''difficult'' others.

Comment: By the way, the most pure definition of the wedge product is using it universal property. So, since the factors does not affect it, all of your definitions above are good (correct, acceptable).